# MacBook Pro 2,2 OS X 10.7.5 and Java

Tags: macos, java, web-browser

Is it possible to get Java working inside a web browser?

I have Chrome and Arctic Fox installed.

The issue I have is that certain web pages wont load and/or work correctly... Mainly docker web GUIs that need Java.

Please, I don't want to hear...

1. Security
2. Outdated hardware
3. Linux

EDIT: What I have already tried

1. Downloading latest Java from the Java website: The installer cant be
   launched
2. Going inside the .app container and running
   /resources/JavaAppletPlugin.pkg: Installation fails

OS X 10.7.5 Is fully up to date

Comment: What research have you done so far? https://java.com/en/download/faq/java_mac.xml first hit on Google for "java os x"

Comment: Obviously I tried downloading the latest java from the java website. The installer cant be launched even though it says it supports 10.7.5. Its not as simple as just installing java... thats why I am here.

Comment: Then you should include this & any other relevant information in your question… it saves other people wasting their time covering ground you've already covered. We cannot see over your shoulder. You have to tell us what you've done & what didn't work, what error messages you got, etc.

Comment: Right ye, sorry. I will edit the question

Comment: I know you don't want to hear "outdated hardware," so you have an *outdated operating system*.  Since you can't upgrade any further, then inherently, your hardware is outdated.  According to the [Java System Requirements for v7 and v8](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/sysreq.xml) you need to be running macOS 10.8.3 or newer.  With your current system you are limited to a maximum of Java 6

Comment: I know it is no longer supported, but why cant I pretend like its 2010 and run that version of Java? From what I understand Apple disabled Java on OS X 10.7.5. There must be a way to get it back?

Comment: This is oracle. What exact java did you try

Comment: No way to get apple java back

Comment: You can obtain older versions of Java from the [Java Archive](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/oracle-java-archive-downloads.html).  It literally says “self-service” so, you’re on your own for support and especially security

Comment: Current browsers don't support Java Applets at all, so you will need an old version of the browser as well.

Comment: @greg-449 - that's not in itself an issue, 10.7.5 can't run anything newer than Safari 6, last updated 2014